# How to replace multiple values read from XML and store it to SQL Database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a Stored Procedure where I need to read values from an XML file and replace that values to a more human-readable format and than store it to the database. 
For Ex.:- The value in tag  'NAT_FLAVOR' has to replaced by 'Natural Flavor' and 'ART_FLAVOR' to 'Artificial Flavor' and then it needed to be stored in the database.

```
   <FSPROJECTMATRIX_0>
        <PROJECT_CODE>O6UJ9A0000Z2</PROJECT_CODE>
        <DM_OBJECT_TYPE>PROJECT0</DM_OBJECT_TYPE>
        <FIELD1>1</FIELD1>
        <FIELD2>tEST123</FIELD2>
        <FIELD3 />
        <FIELD4>4</FIELD4>
        <FIELD5>OZ</FIELD5>
        <FIELD6>2019-03-27 05:00:00.000</FIELD6>
        <FIELD14>NAT_FLAVOR</FIELD14>
        <FIELD15 />
        <FIELD16>Q6UJ9A00O7X1</FIELD16>
        <FIELD17 />
    </FSPROJECTMATRIX_0>
    <FSPROJECTMATRIX_0>
        <PROJECT_CODE>O6UJ9A0000Z2</PROJECT_CODE>
        <DM_OBJECT_TYPE>PROJECT0</DM_OBJECT_TYPE>
        <FIELD1>1</FIELD1>
        <FIELD2>TES456</FIELD2>
        <FIELD3 />
        <FIELD4>4</FIELD4>
        <FIELD5>OZ</FIELD5>
        <FIELD6>2019-03-27 05:00:00.000</FIELD6>
        <FIELD14>ART_FLAVOR</FIELD14>
        <FIELD15 />
        <FIELD16>Q6UJ9A00O7X2</FIELD16>
        <FIELD17 />
    </FSPROJECTMATRIX_0>
```

I Tried IF-ELSE Statement and it's working if only the tag 'FSPROJECTMATRIX_0' comes once in a file. If the tag comes multiple time then I am facing a problem.

```
DECLARE @COE_BUS_TEMP1 VARCHAR(100) = (SELECT fsxml.value('(FSPROJECT/C_BUSUNIT/text())[1]','VARCHAR(64)') FROM @fsxmlIN.nodes('/DataArea/fsxml') AS TEMPTABLE(fsxml))
DECLARE @COENATURALUS_11 VARCHAR(100) = (SELECT fsxml.value('(FIELD14/text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') FROM @fsxmlIN.nodes('/DataArea/fsxml') AS TEMPTABLE(fsxml))
DECLARE @COENATURALEU_11 VARCHAR(100) = (SELECT fsxml.value('(FIELD17/text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') FROM @fsxmlIN.nodes('/DataArea/fsxml') AS TEMPTABLE(fsxml))
DECLARE @SAMPLEUOM_TEMP1 VARCHAR(100) = (SELECT fsxml.value('(FIELD5/text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') FROM @fsxmlIN.nodes('/DataArea/fsxml/FSPROJECT/FSPROJECTMATRIX_0') AS TEMPTABLE(fsxml))

IF @COE_BUS_TEMP1 = 'FRAGRANCE' OR @COE_BUS_TEMP1 = 'FLAVOR_US'
BEGIN
 IF @COENATURALUS_11 = 'NATURAL' SET @COENATURALUS_11 = 'All Natural'
 IF @COENATURALUS_11 = 'ART_FLAVOR' SET @COENATURALUS_11 = 'Artificial Flavor'
 IF @COENATURALUS_11 = 'NAT_ART' SET @COENATURALUS_11= 'Natural AND Artificial'
 IF @COENATURALUS_11 = 'NAT_FLAVOR' SET @COENATURALUS_11 = 'Natural Flavor'
 IF @COENATURALUS_11 = 'SYNTHETIC' SET @COENATURALUS_11 = 'Synthetic'
 IF @COENATURALUS_11 = 'UNKNOWN' SET @COENATURALUS_11 = 'Unknown'
END
```

Thanks in Advance guys.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? (The above code wont run on both...)

Comment: I am using SQL Server Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate suggestions:

1. Store the XML as is in a table named FSPROJECTMATRIX_0, then create a SQL view which does the replacement based on the column value.  This keeps the original field values but does not keep the original XML.
2. Convert the XML file into a temp table or table variable, then do the replacements when inserting the data into the final destination table.   SELECT INTO allows for the input to be a SQL query.
3. Do straight string replacement on the XML text file including the <> xml tag before processing the XML file.  Not recommended.
4. If the XML file comes from a SQL server, do the field translation at the data source instead of the data destination.  Select against a SQL view for example to do the data extract.  Also, use a format other than XML as it is quite slow inside SQL Server.

Comment: XML processing inside SQL Server works but is slow and very error prone.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `xpath`, rather the sql `if-else-codition` to modify contents of your xml.

```
SET @fsxmlIN.modify('replace value of (//FSPROJECT/FSPROJECTMATRIX_0/FIELD14[text()="NAT_FLAVOR"]/text())[1] with "Natural Flavor"')
SET @fsxmlIN.modify('replace value of (//FSPROJECT/FSPROJECTMATRIX_0/FIELD14[text()="NATURAL"]/text())[1] with "All Natural"')
SET @fsxmlIN.modify('replace value of (//FSPROJECT/FSPROJECTMATRIX_0/FIELD14[text()="NAT_ART"]/text())[1] with "Natural AND Artificial"')
SET @fsxmlIN.modify('replace value of (//FSPROJECT/FSPROJECTMATRIX_0/FIELD14[text()="ART_FLAVOR"]/text())[1] with "Artificial Flavor"')
SET @fsxmlIN.modify('replace value of (//FSPROJECT/FSPROJECTMATRIX_0/FIELD14[text()="SYNTHETIC"]/text())[1] with "Synthetic"')

select @fsxmlIN
```